# How to get an image from Android YAFFS2 and be able to mount/read it?

Tags: android, image, mount, dd

For academic/forensic reasons I want to get an image from my SmartPhone and study it.
The File System is YAFFS2.
From adb shell and using  'cat proc/mtd' I can see that I have for partitions: system,appslog,cache,userdata.
I can get the four images using dd command, like 'dd if=/dev/mtd/mtd1 of=/mnt/sdcard/appslog.img bs=4096',
and then using pull command to get data.

-> Is it a good idea to have a format file like .img?
-> How to study (mount/ just read) these *.img files?

..I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

An .img file is less likely to be read as an image file by the Open Source forensic tool Autopsy 3.3.3 (+ Sleuth Kit) [Latest Release at the time being]. However, it can still be opened as a logical file set.Nonetheless, I suggest that you should save it in .dd format instead.